# how to drop columns from a table in impala

Tags: impala, hue

I got a table with more than 2000 columns, but i need to drop only one column
There is any efficient way to make it in impala?

I'm trying this way:

```
alter table proceso.prueba drop subsegm
select * from proceso.prueba
```

but, i got this error in the "select":

```
 'hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/proceso.db/prueba/914a7dd4a8462ff1- 
860a4c1d00000011_978927331_data.1.parq' has an incompatible Parquet schema 
for column 'proceso.prueba.nfi_meses_antiguedad_bco'. Column type: INT, 
Parquet schema: optional byte_array subsegm [i:4 d:1 r:0]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the schema defined for the table (datatype of columns in this case) is conflicting with the schema present in the corresponding Parquet files of the table.

To fix this, you can check the below,

1. Perform a `SHOW CREATE TABLE proceso.prueba` and list the columns.
2. Run the command `parquet-tools meta hdfs://nameservice1/user/hive/warehouse/proceso.db/prueba/914a7dd4a8462ff1- 
   860a4c1d00000011_978927331_data.1.parq` to see the metadata that includes the column details.
3. Compare the results from #1, #2 to see if the number of columns are correct and see if the datatype for the column `subsegm` (in #2 result) is equivalent to what it is supposed to have (in #1 result).
4. Modifying the table datatype to the correct value, structure (if needed) should help you fix this issue.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The second instruction doesnt run!

Comment: You might have to download parquet-tools to run the command. Are you facing any errors even if you have a parquet-tools jar?

Comment: but assume that we need to modify the data type. How can i do it?

Comment: @JuanDavid . You can download parquet-tools from here. You can also read there to get to know about it. Link: https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools

Comment: To modify the datatype - You need to run ATLER TABLE statements in Impala. 

`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name new_name new_type;`

Sidenote: Changing datatype in Parquet file is not easy. The whole file needs to be regenerated from source with the new datatype. So, changing the datatype at Metastore level is the good work-around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196823/discussion-between-gomz-and-juan-david).